# Javascript - FullCalendar [Library]

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I'm trying to implement FullCalendar in one of my Laravel application. I can see the calendar using the code below.

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar();
```

This shows the calendar on the web page, but now what I am looking for is to get the date started from current date or the day which I specify for next 31 days.

I have tried a few variations and none of them worked as expected, the nearest that I had achieved is with week view, but I want this with month view, any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

So you want to start from next 31 days, to next 62 days?

Set `validRange` this way

```
{
    start: '2018-09-17',
    end: '2018-10-17,
}
```

To make it dynamic from now, you can use JS `Date` Object or `moment` package. Since you already load `moment` for FullCalendar, I suggest just use `moment`: `moment().add(1, 'month')` for a month from now, and `moment().add(2, 'month')` for two months from now.

Here's a full example of monthly view and start from next month to 2 month later.

```js
$(function(){
  $('#calendar1').fullCalendar({
    defaultView: 'month',
    validRange: {
      start: moment().add(1, 'month'),
      end: moment().add(2, 'month'),
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.9.0/fullcalendar.min.css"></link>
<div id="calendar1"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.9.0/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I am looking to customize the calendar in such a way the the date in calendar starts from the date which I will define. For example 1 want the calendar to start from 20th of Aug to next 31 days.

Comment: what do you want to define? You can set `start` to `moment('2018-10-19')` and set `end` to `moment('2018-10-19').add(1, 'month')`

Comment: Start and end to be define in validRanges?? Or else where sine validRanges seems not be working the way I am looking

Comment: Check the above code that you have shared, on running the code snippet, it creates a calendar, now what I want is the calendar should start from today's date as opposed to 1st

Comment: set your validRange to `{start: moment(), end: moment().add(1, 'days')}`

Comment: Yes, it creates the calendar, but the issue is it creates the calendar from the 1st of this Month, whereas I want the calendar to start from today the 19th